# Keep only modified rows in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window, window-functions

I need to clean a dataset filtering only modified rows (compared to the previous one) based on certain fields (in the example below we only consider cities and sports, for each id), keeping only the first occurrence.
If a row goes back to a previous state (but not for the immediately preceding), I still want to keep it.

`Input df1`

| id | city | sport | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | london | football | 2022-02-11 |
| **abc** | **paris** | **football** | **2022-02-12** |
| *abc* | *paris* | *football* | *2022-02-13* |
| *abc* | *paris* | *football* | *2022-02-14* |
| *abc* | *paris* | *football* | *2022-02-15* |
| abc | london | football | 2022-02-16 |
| abc | paris | football | 2022-02-17 |
| **def** | **paris** | **volley** | **2022-02-10** |
| *def* | *paris* | *volley* | *2022-02-11* |
| ghi | manchester | basketball | 2022-02-09 |

`Output DESIDERED`

| id | city | sport | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | london | football | 2022-02-11 |
| **abc** | **paris** | **football** | **2022-02-12** |
| abc | london | football | 2022-02-16 |
| abc | paris | football | 2022-02-17 |
| **def** | **paris** | **volley** | **2022-02-10** |
| ghi | manchester | basketball | 2022-02-09 |

Comment: `drop_duplicates` on sorted data should do the job

Comment: That is? could you specify please? drop_duplicates shouldn't work for my purpose, maybe.

Comment: Does "id" play any role in this? For example, if all records in given sample input are unique ids, then what is the expected output?

Comment: Yes, I need to do this for each ID. 
Inside each id I have to check the first change that took place.

Comment: You must have a key which defines order to the data, so if your data is randomised, you can sort it back to proper order and still your expected result is not affected. Which is such key attribute or a combination of attributes in your data? Is it "id" and "date"?

Comment: ID is the key. Date allows you to sort and take the first occurrence. It is also used to understand that if an ID returns to the old "city" and "sport" (not in the immediate previous one) I have to resume them. See example to understand what I mean. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a lag function to compare over a hash :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

output_df = (
    df.withColumn("hash", F.hash(F.col("city"), F.col("sport")))
    .withColumn(
        "prev_hash", F.lag("hash").over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date"))
    )
    .where(~F.col("hash").eqNullSafe(F.col("prev_hash")))
    .drop("hash", "prev_hash")
)


output_df.show()
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| id|      city|     sport|      date|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|abc|    london|  football|2022-02-11|
|abc|     paris|  football|2022-02-12|
|abc|    london|  football|2022-02-16|
|abc|     paris|  football|2022-02-17|
|def|     paris|    volley|2022-02-10|
|ghi|manchester|basketball|2022-02-09|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what this procedure does? Thank you

Comment: @Jresearcher [`hash`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hash) - [`lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag)

Comment: 1 - create a hash, 2 - get the previous hash ordered by date, 3 - compare the hashes, 4 - drop useless columns ...

Comment: Ok Steven, so basically I need to create a hash with all the columns I need to check for changes... right? thank you

Answer (score -1):

Though following solution works for the given data, there are 2 things:

- Spark's architecture is not suitable for serial processing like this.
- As I pointed out in the comment, you must have a key attribute or combination of attributes which can bring your data back in order if it gets fragmented. A slight change in partitioning and fragmentation can change the results.

The logic is:

- Shift "city" and "sport" row by one index.
- Compare with this row's "city" and "sport" with these shifted values. If you see a difference, then that is a new row. For similar rows, there will be no difference. For this we use Spark's Window util and a "dummy_serial_key".
- Filter the data which matches above condition.

You can feel free to add more columns as per your data design:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["abc","london","football","2022-02-11"],["abc","paris","football","2022-02-12"],["abc","paris","football","2022-02-13"],["abc","paris","football","2022-02-14"],["abc","paris","football","2022-02-15"],["abc","london","football","2022-02-16"],["abc","paris","football","2022-02-17"],["def","paris","volley","2022-02-10"],["def","paris","volley","2022-02-11"],["ghi","manchester","basketball","2022-02-09"]], schema=["id","city","sport","date"])

df = df.withColumn("date", F.to_date("date", format="yyyy-MM-dd"))
df = df.withColumn("dummy_serial_key", F.lit(0))
dummy_w = Window.partitionBy("dummy_serial_key").orderBy("dummy_serial_key")
df = df.withColumn("city_prev", F.lag("city", offset=1).over(dummy_w))
df = df.withColumn("sport_prev", F.lag("sport", offset=1).over(dummy_w))
df = df.filter(
    (F.col("city_prev").isNull())
    | (F.col("sport_prev").isNull())
    | (F.col("city") != F.col("city_prev"))
    | (F.col("sport") != F.col("sport_prev"))
)
df = df.drop("dummy_serial_key", "city_prev", "sport_prev")

+---+----------+----------+----------+
| id|      city|     sport|      date|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|abc|    london|  football|2022-02-11|
|abc|     paris|  football|2022-02-12|
|abc|    london|  football|2022-02-16|
|abc|     paris|  football|2022-02-17|
|def|     paris|    volley|2022-02-10|
|ghi|manchester|basketball|2022-02-09|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Is there an error on window order? orderBy('id', 'date') maybe?

Comment: Are you getting any error? I did not get any error; but I'm raising the concern for the need of an attribute or a group of attributes to order the data because in the distributed architecture the order of imported rows is not guaranteed unless explicitly sorted.

Comment: Hi Azhar... I not downvote your answer. Btw I don't understand your orderBy in the window function.

Comment: The comment was for the down-voter to know the reason. BTW, the logic for window function is the to have some key to order by. In your case, it seems to be the appearance of record. Though there is a "date" column, I don't see it playing role in order - that's why I asked for the key attributes to order. The window logic introduces a dummy key with constant value "0". Since you don't have any key, I used constant "0". The window functions like lag() require the window with order by clause.

Comment: Did the solution work for you?